# Laravel deploy on subdomain

Tags: laravel, deployment

I created new subdomain on GoDaddy and compressed my project file as zip and uploaded to public_html/subdomain_name and I modified sub-domain document-root to /public_html/subdomain_name/public and when I am trying to reach 'www.my-project.com/subdomain_name' I just see this

[image: Error]

Comment: Configuring a web server is not on-topic for this site, which deals with programming questions. You'll need to configure your server correctly to serve the Laravel project, there should be plenty of resources out there explaining how to do this.

Answer (score -1):

Create a .htaccess file inside of your projects root directory and insert these lines into that .htaccess file. (Example path: C:/xampp/htdocs/blog_project_root/.htaccess)

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  
  <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule ^ ^$1 [N]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (\.\w+$) [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ server.php

</IfModule>
```

Comment: The `.htaccess` file is provided with Laravel, and it goes in the `public` directory, and only does anything with Apache servers.